# Horizontal UIScrollView with infinite loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uiscrollview, infinite

How can I make an infinite looping view for horizontal `UIScrollView`?

[Example of what I want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrt1hztplske5pw/527c9c606803faa762000000_1.gif?dl=0)

Let's say I have a collection `var subViews = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. I want to create  `UIScrollView` with this collection

```
for subview in subViews {
   uiscrollview.addSubview(subview)
}
```

but I don't want to fill my `ScrollView` with all items on that collection. It should be only three items always like `[1,2,3]` or `[2,3,4]` or `[5,6,1]`

I have found [this library](https://github.com/hirat/DDScrollViewController), but its Objective-C.

Thanks in advance.

**Upadate:**

```
 let page = Int(floor((pageScrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

    let firstPage = page - 1
    let lastPage = page + 1

        for index in 0..<subViews.count{
            let subview = subViews[index]
            if index != firstPage || index != lastPage {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
                subpageViewControlls[index] = nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use objective-c library in swift by adding a bridge header. See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: thanks but i have already done lots of things with ScrollView Delegate, so now i cant switch to this objective-c class. all i need same logic/algorithm like that objective-c lib.

Comment: I would think twice about this if I were you. `UIPageViewController` does exactly what you want, but it looks like you've written code to hook into other stuff. Chances are you'll find it easier to refactor your code to use a library (which in turn probably means Objective-C) or `UIPageViewController` then just find a different way to do your "lots of things with ScrollView delegate."

Comment: please check this screen capture video  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mow33cab4qfk6v9/screen.mov?dl=0), I think its impossible to do with `UIPageViewController` (top navigation)

Comment: I'm reading your updated code. What's going on with the multiplication by 2.0? I think you should consider using Xcode's view debugging to see exactly where your views are going.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here. First, something like [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) would let you create infinitely looped views very easily – you just tell it how you want each view configured, and you're done. I would suggest that this is the preferred solution for ease and also maintainability.

A second solution is to use `UIPageViewController` to handle swiping between pages, but that would require you to implement the looping yourself. Thanks to the way `UIPageViewController` is implemented, this is trivial: just make sure you use modulus or similar in these two:

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController)
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController)
```

Both of these options lazy load so you would never have to load more than three views at a time.

**Update**: OP has commented that they have lots of code for the scroll view delegate already. Assuming they are unable to replace that code and use something like `UIPageViewController`, the solution here effectively is to recreate the behaviour of `UIPageViewController` inside the existing scroll view that is being used. Warning: I would not recommend this solution compared to using something dedicated for this job.

1) Implement `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` so you know when the user scrolled.

2) Calculate which "page" they are on using something like `let page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - yourPageWidthHere / 2) / yourPageWidthHere) + 1;` (written from memory; please check!)

3) Pre-load all pages in your array that are at that page +/- 1. Unload all other pages, replacing them with `NSNull` in your view controllers array so that the positions don't move.

4) Update your scroll view's `contentSize` property to allow the user to continue scrolling. If you wanted to jump them back to an earlier point you could do, but I don't think this would have any effect on performance.

Comment: please check this screen capture video  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mow33cab4qfk6v9/screen.mov?dl=0), I think its impossible to do with `UIPageViewController` (top navigation)

Comment: I've provided a solution based on `UIScrollView`. It's not hard to do this way, but it does require quite a bit of code.

Comment: NB: If you've never managed an array of view controllers, Apple's "PageControl" sample code will help you get started. In particular, see [this file where the exact approach is used](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Listings/Classes_iPhone_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Classes_iPhone_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_20)

Comment: Right; that link above shows how to fill a view controller array with `NSNull` and load/unload the required view controllers as needed.

Comment: @JohnTravolta: The Apple sample code I gave you has a complete, working example of my solution in action; if you've made a mistake porting it into your app, it might be tricky for us to debug.